# How to terminate c# vsto command process with key stroke?

Tags: c#, command, vsto, terminate

I built a C# VSTO Excel Addin, and it has command to delete unused styles looping through used ranges of each WorkSheet. The problem is that in may cases it takes too long, and in such case I want to stop the command process with escape key. How could I implement such feature in by C# VSTO code?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to send ESC key.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Application.SendKeys("{ESC}"); }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
```